# Understanding the proof of the following non context free language

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

Prove that the following language is non-context free by using the pumping lemma
L2 = {w#x | w is a substring of x for w, x ∈ {0, 1}}.

Assume that L2 is context-free. Let p be the pumping length of L2 and s = 10p#10p. By the pumping lemma for context-free languages, we have s = uvxyz   satisfying the following:
• $uv^ixy^i$ z ∈ L2 for i = 0, 1, 2, . . ., and
• |vy| > 0, and
• |vxy| ≤ p.
We do a case analysis here.
• Either v or y contains #. Then uvvxyyz contains more than one #’s, which contradicts uvvxyyz ∈ L2.
• vxy occurs before #. Then uvvxyyz = w1#w2 for some w1, w2 such that w1 is longer than w2. Therefore, w1 cannot be a substring of w2, contradicting uvvxyyz ∈ L2.
• vxy occurs after #. Then uxz = w1#w2 for some w1, w2 such that w1 is longer than w2. Therefore, w1 cannot be a substring of w2, contradicting uxz ∈ L2.
• x straddles #. We have two subcases.
– y begins with 1. Then uxz = w1#w2 for some w1, w2 such that w1 begins with 1 and w2
consists of 0’s. Therefore, w1 cannot be a substring of w2, contradicting uxz ∈ L2.
– y = $\epsilon$. Then uvvxyyz = w1#w2 for some w1, w2 such that w1 is longer than w2. Therefore, w1 cannot be a substring of w2, contradicting uvvxyyz ∈ L2.
Therefore, L2 is not context-free.

Hello everyone, I am having a hard-time understanding how the pumping lemma for context free languages work when it comes to splitting the task into cases. I have the following questions:

How do we see all the cases that we have to cover?

I am having troubles understanding the last step of the latter proof. What does straddle mean in that context?.

why do we need to cover all those cases if just one case would contradict the whole thing?

Comment: "$x$ straddles #" simply means that it starts to its left of it and ends to its right.

Comment: Yes(.............)

Comment: You need all the cases because you want to prove that you've found a word that, when pumped, is definitely not in $L2$.  Since you can only conjecture how this word is decomposed into $u$, $v$, $x$, $y$, and $z$, you need to consider all ways in which that may happen.

Comment: What does finding a word mean?. By proving the cases, we are finding different words that disprove the claim right?

Comment: No, as I clarified in my edit, we are considering all ways in which it may be split.  The pumping lemma only guarantees that there is *some* way in which our word $s$ may be written as $uvxyz$.

Comment: Ok but in each case , there maybe some strings that actually work but others that don't, so finding one that doesn't work in each case is sufficient right?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that for each case, it is enough to show that one of the words obtained by pumping $s$ is not in $L2$ to obtain a contradiction.

Comment: So in the x straddles # just one case is sufficient

Comment: No, because you need to prove that both subcases lead to a contradiction. Otherwise, a reader of that proof may object that in case, say, 4(b) there is no contradiction and therefore the language could be context-free provided $s$ splits as in case 4(b).

Comment: But there are thre may be cases that are not covered which lead to a contradiction

Comment: The case analysis must be exhaustive, or else the proof is not complete.

Comment: For example in the last case, what about y begins with 0?

Comment: OK. I had to look at the solution you posted.  This problem is in Sipser's book; the second edition also has a solution, which is similar to this one, but picks a different word: $s=1^p0^p\#1^p0^p$.  The different choice is critical precisely for the case in which $x$ straddles $\#$, because then you can invoke the condition $|vxy|\leq p$ to show that $uv^2xy^2z$ contains more $0$s on the left-hand side of the $\#$ than on the right-hand side, which means that $w_1$ cannot be a substring of $w_2$.